# VueJS - Sorting an CountBy Array created by lodash

Tags: vue.js, lodash

Got following .json:

```
[{
"STATUS": "0500",
"POSID": "..."
},
{
"STATUS": "1500",
"POSID": "..."
},
{
"STATUS": "0500",
"POSID": "..."
}]
```

Counted the values via countBy from lodash:

```
  countData (data) {
    return _.countBy(_.map(this.data, function (d) {
      return d.status
    }))
  }
```

A table is generated where my status numbers and counts are displayed:

```
 <tr v-for="(value, key) in countData">
   <td>{{ key }}</td>
   <td>{{ value }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Now I want to sort that via value.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `countData` is already a computed property, so if you need to keep it, you can refer to it from another computed property (as `this.countData`) which should provide the sorted version of the results for presentation.

For example,

```
computed: {
  countData () { ... },
  sortedCountData () {
    // this.countData looks something like: {'0500': 1, ...}
    return Object.keys(this.countData)
      .sort((i, j) => this.countData[j] - this.countData[i])
      .map(key => ({ key, value: this.countData[key] }));
  },
}
```

Then you should update your markup so the `v-for` sources from `sortedCountData` instead.

If you don't need to keep `countData`, you may as well do the sorting there.

Comment: Is it right that i have to name the tds: 
                        <td>{{ value.key }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.value }}</td> ?

Comment: Yes, that's right—since `sortedCountData` is a proper array and no longer a object (as returned by the lodash `countBy` call), each item `v-for` iterates over is also an object, so you'll need to index into the `key` and `value` properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the array before rendering. OR alternatively you can use css to do this.

```
<tbody style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"> 
// <tbody> or <table> if parent is <table> tag 
  <tr v-for="(value, key) in countData" style="order:{{value}}">
  <td>{{key}}</td>
  <td>{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

you need to give fixed width on td in case it gets distorted

Comment: - style="order:{{ value }}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div style="{{ val }}">, use <div :style="val">.

-> But wont work either.